# Excel - Using a formula that is entered as text in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

(I originally posted this on Stack Overflow, but was told this was a more appropriate forum.)

I have been researching this for a while now, and cannot make any progress. I feel like this should be pretty easy? I'd appreciate any input.

I am working on a spreadsheet with a lot of calculations on various groups of cells. Let's say the data is in A1:A10.

Instead of entering this range in each formula:

=average(a1:a10)
=min(a1:a10)
=stdev.s(a1:a10)
...and so on...

I would rather enter this range as text into a cell (say T1), and have the various functions reference it:

=average(use the range entered in T1 to calculate)
...and so on...

I thought the INDIRECT function was going to be the answer, but I couldnt get it to work.

I'd really like to do this with native Excel functions (not VBA or macros or anything along those lines).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The INDIRECT function is indeed what you want. If you store "a1:a10" (without the quotes) in cell T1, you can use:

```
=Average(Indirect(T1))
```

to get the average of the values in A1:A10.

If you want to refer to a range on a different sheet, you need to specify the name of the sheet as part of the address. So if you want to refer to A1:A10 on the worksheet called OtherSheet, you would store "OtherSheet!A1:A10" in cell T1.

Note that this only allows you to get the address of a cell or range from another cell (as your question asks), not a whole formula (as your title asks).

Comment: I was able to get that to work, but in this case the cells I am trying to reference are on another sheet in the same workbook.  I didnt think that would be the issue, but I tried it on the same sheet and it works.  Is the INDIRECT function limited to the current sheet?

Comment: Ref: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-change-a-cell-reference-c7b8b95d-c594-4488-947e-c835903cebaa

Comment: @jj95 To refer to an address on another worksheet, just put the sheet name followed by `!` before the cell address. I have edited the answer to include an example.

Comment: Note that you may reference other Excel *files* too, not just sheets. But generally you must have the referenced files open - it might be a security setting that sets that requirement.

Comment: Got it!  

I was taking the range I had and pasting it into the cell that I wanted to use.  In this case, the sheet name was wrapped in tick marks (').  When I pasted it, the leading tick mark was dropped (tell Excel to treat this as text).  I added another tick mark and it worked like a champ.

Thanks all for the help!!